# how many ways can 48 people divide into 8 groups of 6

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

so I can think of 2 method but they give different answers which confuse me:

1st one is 48c6 x 42c6 x 36c6 x 30c6 x 24c6 x 18c6 x 12c6 x 6c6

each time you choose 6 people from the rest for 8 times

2nd one is 48!/((6!)^8 x 8!)

so choose 1 people from the rest for 48times, then divided by 6! 8 times since there are 8 groups and each groups has 6 people, to prevent duplicate counting since order doesnt matter, then divided by 8! since group order doesnt matter as well.

but this 2 methods have different answers, but both make sense to me, so which one is correct?

Comment: The only difference seems to be the $8!$ in the denominator of the second.  As you say, that is correct if the order of the groups does not matter.

Comment: If I were you, I would read Brian M Scott's answer over and over again, until my *intuition* was stretched to the point that it **got it**.  If, during this process, your intuition *screams for mercy*, be ruthless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your first approach is that it badly overcounts. Suppose that your groups are A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and H. Your first calculation counts them $8!$ times: once when you choose them in the order ABCDEFGH, once when you choose them in the order ABCDEFHG, and so on, with a count for every possible order in which you could choose $8$ things. Since the overcounting is uniform, meaning that you’ve counted every set of groups the same number of times, you can easily correct for it: just divide your first result by $8!$.

You can also reason as follows. Imagine that we’ve numbered the people $1$ through $48$. There are $\binom{47}5$ ways to choose the other $5$ members of the group that contains person $1$. Let $k$ be the smallest number of a person **not** in that first group; there are $\binom{41}5$ ways to choose the other $5$ members of the group containing person $k$. Repeating this process six more times, we find that there are

$$\binom{47}5\binom{41}5\binom{35}5\binom{29}5\binom{23}5\binom{17}5\binom{11}5\binom55\tag{1}$$

ways to choose the $8$ groups. Note that

$$\binom{6n}6=\frac{6n}6\binom{6n-1}5=n\binom{6n-1}5\,,$$

so your product is indeed $8!$ times the product in $(1)$.

Comment: so the 2nd method is also correct?

Comment: @WardenHuang: Yes; it’s equivalent to $(1)$ and to the corrected version of your first method.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning about

> then divided by 8! since group order doesnt matter as well

should apply to both methods. And in fact,

$$ {48 \choose 6}{42 \choose 6}{36 \choose 6}{30 \choose 6}{24 \choose 6}{18 \choose 6}{12 \choose 6}{6 \choose 6} \frac{1}{8!} = \frac{48!}{(6!)^8 8!} $$

Answer (score 0):

The groups are not fixed

$\frac{\binom{48}{6}\times\binom{42}{6}\times\binom{36}{6}\times\binom{30}{6}\times\binom{24}{6}\times\binom{18}{6}\times\binom{12}{6}\times\binom{6}{6}}{8!}$